# Mapping printers with SBS 2003 R1

Tags: group-policy, windows-sbs-2003, network-printer

We have an SBS 2003 R1 domain controller, and a mixture of Windows 7 and XP (domain-joined) workstations.

There are 20 users, 20 PCs, and 5 printers.

Printer drivers for all 5 printers are already installed on each of the 20 workstations, however users have no printers available in their profile if they log on to a PC they have never used before (either leading to IT requests, or the user simply putting up with a loss of functionality if they use a different computer during a meeting in another office etc.)

There is only one server, so I am not sure how we can safely upgrade to SBS 2003 R2, as there is no other server to fall back on if something goes wrong during the upgrade. I would love to upgrade to R2, but I just don't see how I can safely proceed with only one server.

What options do we have for mapping printers at logon which *don't* involve having to upgrade the server from SBS 2003 -> SBS 2003 R2 ?

**Edit:**

All printers are shared from the same PC on the network.

I have numbered them for the purposes of this question:

**\\server1\printer1**

**\\server1\printer2**

**\\server1\printer3**

**\\server1\printer4**

I would like my solution to also:

- delete all existing printers at logon before mapping these printers (we have some invalid print queues lingering in various user profiles on various PCs, which occasionally cause confusion)
- ideally not display a command prompt window when users log on (even briefly)

[image]

Comment: Surely someone has some ideas?

Comment: Often this is done w/ a combination of Group Policy & vbs scripts. There are a lot of variables to consider, x86 vs x64, shared vs. direct IP connections, XP vs Win 7 but it can be done. See http://serverfault.com/questions/265436/printers-deployed-using-group-policy?rq=1 for an example.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that all printers are shared with the format "\\server1\printerX"